# Anti-Raid event DiscordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am creating a security discord bot and I would like to know how to include createdAt in an event, and create a command like that `.setwelcomeban 5d` command (for example) which will cause all joining accounts to be automatically kicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get when a member joined a server using the [`joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) or [`joinedTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedTimestamp) property of a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.

You can then [loop](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) through each member in a guild, [compare the current date with the date they joined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/10046076), and [kick the member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) if they joined within the amount of days you specified.

Remember to change the `/* number of days */` part to take the number of days you specify.

```js
message.guild.members.cache.each(member => {
  const date1 = new Date(member.joinedAt).getTime();
  const date2 = new Date().getTime() - /* number of days */ * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  if (date2 < date1) {
    member.kick();
  }
});
```